# Look for the top ten best selling products

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sql-server, ruby

I need to search the top 10 items sold, I have been investigating and I found a method called top that can make this possible, I try to apply it but I get this error:

```
SyntaxError (/home/luis/sites/AdvanceControld/app/models/detalleve.rb:38: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting keyword_end
     query = select top 10('detallevet.Article')
```

What would be the best way to do this search?

```
   def self.best_seller(params)
     query = select top 10('detallevet.Article')
          .joins('left outer join venta ON venta.Documento=detallevet.Docto and venta.RutaId=detallevet.RutaId')
          .where("(venta.RutaId = :rutaId or :rutaId = '') AND (venta.IdEmpresa = :idempresa)",{rutaId: params[:search], idempresa: params[:search0]})
     query = query.where('venta.Fecha >= ? AND venta.Fecha <= ?', (params[:search1].to_date).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), (params[:search2].to_date).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')) if params[:search1].present? and params[:search2].present?
     query
      end
```

The table where the sales data is obtained is detailed (detail) and this table have the products in the Article column.I am relating it to venta (sale) because of this I get data like the date. A venta can have many detallevet and detallevet belongs to a sale

this is the detallevet schema:

```
  create_table "DetalleVet", primary_key: "ID", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.varchar "Article",    limit: 50
    t.integer "Docto",       limit: 4
    t.money   "Importe",                        precision: 19, scale: 4
    t.integer "RutaId",      limit: 4
    t.varchar "IdEmpresa",   limit: 50
  end
```

this is the venta schema

```
  create_table "Venta", primary_key: "Id", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "RutaId",       limit: 4
    .integer  "Documento",    limit: 4
    t.datetime "Fecha"
    t.varchar  "IdEmpresa",    limit: 50
  end
```

Comment: I tried to help you and started writing some code, but without knowing the language you used to name your columns this question is hard to understand and IMHO almost impossible to answer. Can you please post you database schema for the `venta` and `detallevet` database table, show how you defined the associations in that models and add translations to the table and column names?

Comment: @spickermann thanks for answering. updated :)

Answer (score 1):

I have achieved the solution by doing the following query, including both the product and the sales number of the same. I hope it will help somebody else

```
   def self.bestseller
      joins("INNER JOIN detallevet ON productos.Clave = detallevet.Articulo")
             .select("detallevet.Articulo, COUNT(Articulo) as count, productos.Producto")
              .group("detallevet.Articulo, productos.Producto").order("count DESC").limit(10)
    end
```